# AWS lambda function through terraform - Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, terraform

I am using terraform to create lambda function and already have zip package in S3. But I get below error:

```
  RespMetadata: {
    StatusCode: 400,
    RequestID: "fa9b0e8b-02a6-4eaf-81ae-bf30fc6a1153"
  },
  Message_: "Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again.",
  Type: "User"
}
```

My code looks as below:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  s3_bucket = "bucket_name"
  s3_key = "lambda.zip"
  function_name = "Function_Test"
  role = aws_iam_role.test_lambda_role.arn
  handler = "config.lambda_handler"
  runtime = "python3.8"
  timeout = 180
  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids = ["subnet-123"]
    security_group_ids = ["sg-123"]
  }

  environment {
    variables = {
      LOG_LEVEL = "DEBUG"
      host = "https://abc:9098"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There are several similar questions on the site, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63028077/aws-cloudformation-error-could-not-unzip-uploaded-file-please-check-your-file) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35235118/aws-cli-create-lambda-function-cannot-unzip-uploaded-file) - if they don't solve your issue, can you explain why?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver I went through these links and they are using cloudformation or aws-cli command to create Lambda function. I am using terraform to create the function. That is the reason those solutions do not work for me. Also I have my zip file in AWS S3.

Comment: Same account? S3 file is really there? Has the deployer access to S3?

Comment: What is the structure of the zip if you unzip it locally?

Comment: @GuyT yes, I have the zip file in the same account and the deployer has full access. And now I tried to unzip the file using unzip command and I see below ```unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of lambda.zip or
        lambda.zip.zip, and cannot find lambda.zip.ZIP, period```

Comment: @GuyT So I tried ```file lambda.zip
lambda.zip: POSIX tar archive (GNU)```

Comment: So AWS seems to be correct: Could not unzip uploaded file ;)

Answer (score 0):

recently had the same issue with terraform. terraform expects the extension of filename to be a zip and not a python code/extension. the extension of "filename" was .py instead of .zip for me it worked fine when I used the correct extension.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).